# Jdbc connection vs socket connection for connecting database

Tags: java, sockets, jdbc

Can somebody tell me which way is better for fetching the records from db in java.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code for database connections using sockets? i want to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you will write your own database connectivity you're in a for a major project and wheel re-inventing.  Your database must also support direct socket connections and document it so you can write the low level socket lib.  Good luck.

I will go with a JDBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

If there's a JDBC driver for your database, I would definitely use it. Programming a database connection on socket level would soon get very low-level - assuming you know the protocol. For open source databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL, specs might be available describing that protocol, but they are most likely not available for closed source databases like Oracle, MS SQL or DB2.

Plus, if you use JDBC, you can focus on what **your** program must do, instead of spending a lot of time on something that was already solved for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use JDBC, then you will have a jar driver for your particular database, which handles the access details. If you write a direct connect to your database via sockets, then it's not JDBC, unless you write your own JDBC driver and in this case you don't have a choice anyway.